# Java script how do i properly use drawimage in a class method

Tags: javascript, class, methods, scope, element

I have a list of picture variables : skeletonIdle ;
I wanna have a class that draws each one after the other so i have an animation

```
class Skeleton{

    constructor(){

        this.skelframe = 0 ;

    }

    drawSkeleton(){

        this.skelIdle1 = document.getElementById("skel1");
        this.skelIdle2 = document.getElementById("skel2");
        this.skelIdle3 = document.getElementById("skel3");
        this.skelIdle4 = document.getElementById("skel4");
        this.skelIdle5 = document.getElementById("skel5");
        this.skelIdle6 = document.getElementById("skel6");
        this.skelIdle7 = document.getElementById("skel7");
        this.skelIdle8 = document.getElementById("skel8");
        this.skelIdle9 = document.getElementById("skel9");
        this.skelIdle10 = document.getElementById("skel10");

        this.skeletonIdle = [

            this.skelIdle1,
            this.skelIdle2,
            this.skelIdle3,
            this.skelIdle4,
            this.skelIdle5,
            this.skelIdle6,
            this.skelIdle7,
            this.skelIdle8,
            this.skelIdle9,
            this.skelIdle10

        ];
```

I'm trying to iterate through each one and draw it 
so that i will have an animation

```
        this.skelframe += 0.1 ; 



        if (this.skelframe > 9 ){
            this.skelframe = 0 ;
        }

canvasContext.drawImage(this.skeletonIdle[this.skelframe],10,10,100,100);
```

It seems that i cant get drawImage to work in a class 
is it possible to have drawImage in a class . If so how do i do this 
Here is me calling the method .

```
window.onload= function() {

    canvas = document.getElementById("Gamecanvas");
    canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvasContext.fillStyle = 'red' ;
    canvasContext.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    var GlacierImage = document.getElementById("glacier");
    canvasContext.drawImage(GlacierImage,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    skeletonChar.drawSkeleton();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I was needing to use RequestAnimationFrame() as its a better alternative for repainting . And the setInterval() function can cause browsers to bug out.